# How can I show instagram photos in my e-commerce page from Magento Plugin?

Tags: instagram, magento-1.9, photo

[image: Screenshot of problem]

I created a developer instagram account and I had my client-id, client-secret, with the option Disable implicit OAuth checked. I put the same Web Site URL and Valid redirect URLs from instagram's development and it's the same into my Magento configuration, but it didn't work.

When I try to connect instagram into my ecommerce page, it shows me another page with this message (instead of my login and after my instagram photos):

```
{
    "code": 400, 
    "error_type": "OAuthException", 
    "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"
}
```

but when I put in the Instagram Development page my instagram url path and the same url in Valid redirect URLs and Magento Configuration, the page let me login, but still doesn't show me the photos in order to select them. So it still doesn't work.

I'm a beginner in this task, can you help me?

my page is  misimpresiones.com

and this is a video, so you can visit it, and personalice the product for the example:
http://www.misimpresiones.com/media/misimpresiones_Instagram.mp4

Comment: Authentication removed totally, https://magecomp.com/magento-instagram-connect.html Connect with products too

Answer (score 0):

I notice in the popup you have it has force_classic in the URL?

Comment: This page makes the instagram call, I just go to the instagram development page, login  and registered like development, and after that, I followed the instructions from the instagram development page, and searching in google about generation of the TOKEN_ID and found that the TOKEN_ID was the same as the CLIENTE_ID, so I just put the same URL with the CLIEND_ID in the instagram development page (Website URL and Security options) and in the Magento Configuration in the Instagram part.